# How to convert AY music file to FLAC preserving metadata in Linux?

Tags: linux, flac, zxspectrum

I have a bunch of `*.ay` files having some metadata (artist, title and "misc"). How can I convert them to `*.flac` preserving that metadata?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of useful AY-tools with source code on http://bulba.untergrund.net/progr_e.htm:

- AY-files splitter – parses metadata from AY and saves it to simple INI file
- AY to WAV converter

You can try to build them for Linux with Free Pascal. Then write script that pass metadata and wave to some wav-to-flac converter (e.g. ffmpeg).

Also you can make own tool with "YMEngine with SDL" library.